# Is there a way to search for things on a page using an element in html?

Tags: html, search, filter

I want to make a site that allows you to search for something on a page. I'm making a discord bot invite site. I'm aiming for something like on https://dankmemer.lol/commands. You search for a comand and it appears based on what you search up.

Here's an image on what that looks like.

[image]

I haven't tried anything yet, because I don't know where to start.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, ***[search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+find+in+page+site:stackoverflow.com)***; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Yes it is possible. If you don't know where to start, you probably need to have a deeper look at understanding the following concepts: event listeners and array filtering.